# Kernel-headers in openWRT

Tags: kernel-module, openwrt

How to bring kernel-headers in openwrt custom based image?
In the image which it is built by us in which how to bring build file.
/lib/modules/kernel-number-generic/build: No such file or directory.
Which file or directory we want to enable to bring the kernel build in final image.

Comment: `make headers_install # Install sanitised kernel headers to INSTALL_HDR_PATH`

Comment: lede/include/toplevel.mk:216: recipe for target 'headers_install' failed.This is the ERROR I am getting if I use "make headers_install"

Comment: This is not an actual error, this is result of the error

Comment: Hi @0andriy I am not understanding.Could you please explain me a bit more.I am fresher to this cross compilation world.

Comment: The error message had been printed earlier, this one is a result of the failure, i.e. entire target is failed because of some (unknown yet) issue.

Comment: make header_install and make modules_install is available in linux-kernel.But in openWRT the kernel is residing in **build_dir/target-/linux-brcm2708-brcm2710/linux-kernel** So from the top level directory of openWRT build, how can I run **make header_install or make modules_install** .If I give header_install in top-dir it is throwing error as target is not available.

Comment: Ah, okay, it seems you need to patch https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/blob/master/package/kernel/linux/Makefile to call `make headers_install` with proper environment, etc.